# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am trying  to update a column in mysql by adding corresponding rows. Below is just the String that contains the SQL Expression.  Syntax error indicates this needs fixing.

```
qry = UPDATE term1"
+"SET Total_Score =English+Maths"
+" WHERE SID =?";
```

Comment: the syntax error message in full shows where in the query the syntax error is. Please include this.

Answer (score 0):

This question could do with a bit more context I think but looking at your query there seems to be 2 things wrong.

1st is that the double-quotes seem to be missing at the start of the `UPDATE`

2nd there doesn't look like there's a space between the `term1` part and the `SET` part.

Maybe try this:

```
qry = "UPDATE term1 SET Total_Score = English+Maths WHERE SID = ?";
```

Comment: Thank you.  It has to do with spacing.  I figured that out and got it working.